# Mac Navigation Possible with Keyboard Only (QuickSilver Included)?

Tags: windows-xp, mac, itunes, keyboard-shortcuts, quicksilver

I have a **new iMac with Boot Camp** and XP SP3. I used to use Mac OS (1986-2002) but **switched to Windows XP** because I was working in web development and I regularly needed to verify the sites I was working on.

I have gotten used to Windows shortcuts, and find that I can navigate very quickly using just my keyboard. For example, if I want to modify the **track number** of a song in **iTunes**, I can just select the song, **type ctrl-i, alt-t and the number**.

This is one example of many hundreds. In Windows, virtually all menu items or dialog boxes are accessible this way. Another example is changing my Documents window view **from list to thumbnail view**: I hold down **alt** and type **v-d** for detail view or **v-h** for thumbnail view.

The shortcuts are all underlined when I hold down the alt key, which means that **I don't have to memorize long lists of shortcuts** or go looking elsewhere when it's time to use them. Integrating them into my habits is easy because of this.

I bought this iMac (and another one before it) because I genuinely believe that it is a **great computer**, much better built overall than any PC. However, each time I start using Mac OS, I go nuts because I just cannot figure out how to do things quickly without the alt shortcuts. I either spend all my time looking at long lists of shortcuts trying to memorize them or using the mouse. So, I end up using XP with Boot Camp (it's been three years now!).

There are many cases (the iTunes track number above), where **I cannot find any shortcut at all**. If I need to give track numbers to an album of 20 songs, I can do it in 60 keystrokes without using my mouse in XP. On Mac, I can't see how this would be possible.

I have looked at **QuickSilver**, but have not found any way to select individual fields in a multi-field dialog box (again, the iTunes example). And, it requires lots of memorization to keep track of all the shortcuts.

I have activated the **keyboard setting to tab through all fields**, but this is not a usable solution when I have to tab through 6-8 fields to get to the one I want in a repetitive task.

Can anyone suggest an **effective way to navigate in Leopard or Snow Leopard using only the keyboard** (hopefully without having to tab through all the fields in iTunes to change fields)? Is there **some aspect of QuickSilver that I'm missing** that would enable me to do this?

I love my iMac, and this single issue is keeping me from using Snow Leopard full time.

Comment: +1 for the very nicely written question. It's a problem I face as well, but I've yet to find a solution. I have not invested any time in actually trying to learn the QuickSilver way of doing things.

Comment: There is a really good tip at http://www.43folders.com/2007/03/12/tme-quicksilver-application-menus for how to get instant access to all menu items using QuickSilver. It won't help with iTunes info panels, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all buttons have default keys associated to them in Mac applications.  Usually it is the first letter + Cmd + optional other modifier keys.  Next is Cmd-Shift-n

1. Select the first track
2. Get Info (Cmd i)
3. tab to the track number field
4. enter number
5. Cmd-Shift-n for next
6. repeat 4-6 until done

Comment: It's the third step that gets to me -- if I want to change the genre, that's 12 tabs in Leopard, and alt-g in Windows. But I didn't know about the cmd-shift-N for next, thanks.

Comment: True, but relatively painless as you only need to do this once.  The cursor stays in the same place when you cmd-shift-N for next

Comment: For the sake of saving one more keystroke, on my machine cmd-n is enough to switch to the next song, no shifting required.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above there are several ways to do things. Do you have to repetitively change track numbers or is that just an example?

Using Quicksilver (great program) and a knowledge of keyboard shortcuts I can navigate without the mouse very well. It just takes some time, and if you're used to windows shortcuts it can be tricky.

Comment: Adding track numbers, disk numbers, etc. is something I have to do all the time, and it has proven to be particuliarly difficult for me Leopard. I can move between all the fields in the info panel in random order by single keystrokes on a PC, but as far as I know, tabbing is the only way to move between fields on Leopard.

I'm starting to get a feel for what's possible, and I think that QuickSilver will be enough to be able to use all the menu items. It's the song info in iTunes that really has me stumped.

Comment: Yeah, Apple + I will get you the info, along with info in Finder.